# Handling nested loops cleanly in Python

Tags: python

I have the following Python script:

query_parser.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


def count_resources_per_category(resource_names):
    APPS_MAP = {
        'billing': ["paypal", "checkout", "cart", "order-service"],
        'browse': ["content", "localization", "pricing", "search",],
        'some_category': ["random-1", "random-2"],
    }
    results_map = {}
    for key, _ in APPS_MAP.items():
        results_map[key] = 0
    results_map['other'] = 0
    # now we have:
    #   results_map = {
    #     'checkout': 0,
    #     'browse': 0,
    #     'MCM': 0,
    #     'other': 0
    #   }
    for resource_name in resource_names:
        FOUND_IT = False
        for key, app_names in APPS_MAP.items():
            if FOUND_IT:
                break
            for app_name in app_names:
                if app_name in resource_name:
                    results_map[key] += 1
                    FOUND_IT = True
                    break
        if not FOUND_IT:
            results_map['other'] += 1

    return results_map


def determine_if_resource_count_issue(results_map):
    RESULT_FOUND = False
    for key, count in results_map.items():
        if count:
            if RESULT_FOUND:
                print("The script isn't gonna work as planned")
                return True
            RESULT_FOUND = True
    print("All good :)")
    return False


#--------------------------------------------------------------------

""" TESTS """

# test_count_resources_per_category():
test_input = [
    'some-prefix-pricing', # browse
    'some-prefix2-cart', # billing
    'content', # browse
    'some-random-thing-not-found' # other
]
expectation = {
    'browse': 2,
    'billing': 1,
    'some_category': 0,
    'other': 1
}
result = count_resources_per_category(test_input)
assert result == expectation

#--------------------------------------------------------------------

# test_determine_resource_count_issue_passes():
test_input = {
    'browse': 234234234,
    'billing': 0,
    'some_category': 0,
    'other': 0
}
assert False == determine_if_resource_count_issue(test_input)

#--------------------------------------------------------------------

# test_determine_resource_count_issue_fails():
test_input = {
    'browse': 2,
    'billing': 1,
    'some_category': 0,
    'other': 1
}
assert True == determine_if_resource_count_issue(test_input)

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I was wondering what the clean, pythonish way to handle these nested loops would be without the `FOUND_IT` and `RESULT_FOUND` flags.

Comment: You might want to post this in [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: `if not FOUND_IT:` could be just `else:`

Comment: Please make this into a [mcve].

Comment: ty barmar, I read those examples...very disappointing/surprising for a modern language like python